# Extracting the contents of a specific variable from the page source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

He builds his ***site.com*** website and I want to add a panel with news from another ***site2.com*** website. On the ***site2.com*** site news are posted as HTML and JavaScript. To this end, I am trying to extract the data first to download the page content into the **content** variable, the second stage is to extract the variable code.

My current jQuery code:

```
var content = '';
$.get('https://site2.com', function(data){
    content = data;
});
```

Now, I want to extract data from the **news** array from the page code (`var content`).

An example of the content of the **var news** located in content:

```
/* ... */
var news = {
    "name1": 0,
    "name2": 1,
    "name3": 2, 
}
/* ... */
```

How can I do this, do you have an idea / example?

Comment: You already have the data in `content`. Now simply traverse the data you returned from the site.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to extract data from the news variable?

Comment: @urbmake, , if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from answer. In other case please write a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:

```
var name1 = news.name1;
```

And so on...

Or in loop:

```js
var news = {
    "name1": 0,
    "name2": 1,
    "name3": 2
}

for (var i in news)
{
    var value = news[i];
    console.log(value);
}
```